# Is it possible to change site address(site url) only on homepage of the WordPress Website?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I installed WordPress to "wp" directory and now each page's url is like below

```
http://example.com/wp/
http://example.com/wp/access/
http://example.com/wp/contact/ ...
```

but I'd like to remove "wp" only on homepage.
The result I want to get is below

```
http://example.com/
http://example.com/wp/access/
http://example.com/wp/contact/ ...
```

If I change site address(url) settings and index.php on site route,
this removes all the "wp" from all pages.

## site address(url)

```
http://example.com/
```

## index.php on site route

```
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

I'd like to know if it's possible change site url only on homepage.

Answer (score 0):

You can add below page in function.php file and replace http://yoursiteurl.com with your site URL

```
function redirect_homepage() {
    if( ! is_home() && ! is_front_page() )
        return;

    wp_redirect( 'http://yoursiteurl.com', 301 );
    exit;
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_homepage' );
```